# Problema para recorrer un json

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario donde se coloca un nombre y se elige entre 5 tipos distintos de "perfil". 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuyo codigo es el siguiente:

```
<form id="registroForm" name="registroForm" class="ui form" role="form" action="guardar.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="ui segment"> 
        <div class="field">
            <label>Nombre y Apellido:</label>
            <input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre" minlength=3 maxlength=100 required>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <label>Tipo de Perfil:</label>
            <select id="tipoUsuario" class="ui fluid search dropdown" multiple name="clase[]" required>
                <option data-subtext="Debe elegir un item" value="" disabled="disabled">Elija una opción...</option>
                <option value = "1">Clase 1</option>
                <option value = "2">Clase 2</option>
                <option value = "3">Clase 3</option>
                <option value = "4">Clase 4</option>
                <option value = "5">Clase 5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="ui submit red button">Registrarse</div>
        <div class="ui error message"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Tengo dos bases de datos. Una donde guardo los datos basicos y hago lo siguiente:

```
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];

if (isset($_POST['clase'])) {
    $ul_list = json_encode($_POST['clase']);
} else {
    $ul_list = json_encode(array("0"));
}

$conexion = new Conexion();
$stmt = $conexion -> prepare("INSERT INTO prueba (nombre, clase) VALUES (:nombre, :clase)");
$stmt->bindValue(":nombre", $nombre);
$stmt->bindValue(":clase", $ul_list);
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    $resultado = 1;
} else {
    $resultado = null;
}
```

Hasta ahí todo perfecto: los datos que me graba son del formato: 
[id] / [nombre] / [clase]
1      MARIO PEREZ  ["1","3","5"]
2      PEPE ROMERO  ["1","2","5"]
3      JOSE PERDOMO ["1","4"]

Ahora bien, tengo otra base donde tengo esta estructura:
[id] / [nombre] / [clase1] / [clase2] / [clase3] / [clase4] / [clase5]

en cada campo "claseN" quiero guardar un booleano un si o no... y para ello hago lo siguiente:

```
$clase1 = 0;
$clase2 = 0;
$clase3 = 0;
$clase4 = 0;
$clase5 = 0;
$array = json_decode($ul_list, true);

print_r ($array);

foreach ($array as $key=> $values) {
    switch ($values) {
        case 1:
            $clase1 = 1;
        case 2:
            $clase2 = 1;
        case 3:
            $clase3 = 1;
        case 4:
            $clase4 = 1;
        case 5:
            $clase5 = 1;
    }
  }

$conexion = new Conexion();
$stmt = $conexion -> prepare("INSERT INTO prueba2 (nombre, clase1, clase2, clase3, clase4, clase5) VALUES (:nombre, :clase1, :clase2, :clase3, :clase4, :clase5)");
$stmt->bindValue(":nombre", $nombre);
$stmt->bindValue(":clase1", $clase1);
$stmt->bindValue(":clase2", $clase2);
$stmt->bindValue(":clase3", $clase3);
$stmt->bindValue(":clase4", $clase4);
$stmt->bindValue(":clase5", $clase5);
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    $resultado2 = 1;
} else {
    $resultado2 = null;
}
```

resulta que cuando ejecuto el código, todos los campos los deja con el numero 1 y no me respeta los valores del json
Por ejemplo en el ejemplo: 1      MARIO PEREZ  ["1","3","5"]
debería grabar 
1   MARIO PEREZ  1  0  1  0  1 
pero me pone un numero 1 en todos los campos clase... 
que es lo que estoy haciendo mal ?

Comment: Te faltan los `break` en cada `case`

Comment: TAL CUAL !!! ... Gracias @Lixus !!! ponelo como respuesta que califico

Comment: No entendí el asunto. ¿Te fijaste en el `switch`?, en cualquier caso asignas el valor `1` a las variables, ejemplo: `$clase2 = 1;`  ¿Quieres que todas las variables `$clase` valgan `1`? Si es así no sé para qué sirve el bloque `switch ... case`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo te hicieron falta los `break` en cada `case`

```
switch ($values) {
    case 1:
        $clase1 = 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        $clase2 = 1;
        break;
    case 3:
        $clase3 = 1;
        break;
    case 4:
        $clase4 = 1;
        break;
    case 5:
        $clase5 = 1;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

El comentario de Lixus es correcto, sin embargo creo que podrías hacerlo de una forma más simple con [variables variables](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.variable.php), no hay necesidad de un switch para un caso tan sencillo:

```
$clase1 = $clase2 = $clase3 = $clase4 = $clase5 = 0;

$array = json_decode($ul_list, true);

foreach ($array as $key => $values) {
    $varName = 'clase' . $values;
    ${varName} = 1;
}
```

Comment: PUFFFFF @Shaz !!! magia pura !!! En realidad ahi hay otros nombres, pero bien...

Comment: Esto es mucho más práctico... y si fuera yo, hasta modificaría el diseño de los datos. Si el programa evoluciona y tenemos que llegar hasta una `$clase50, $clase51, $claseN...` la cosa se va a complicar terriblemente.